Will a FOIA request from a police department provide information about their Civilian spyware?
During 2020, a local police department utilized spyware on me. Yes, I know it sounds bizarre but it occurred. It's a long and complicated situation that resulted in my husband committing suicide. I know personal information about some of these cops that I should not know. The corruption runs deep. I was threatened and I am terrified because I know just how deep it runs.

I am voting to close, as this is purely a legal question, and off-topic nonetheless. I recommend you talk to a law professional.

We can tell you whether the law says that they should. In practice you may find that they simply deny your request and leave it to you to appeal, or just don't bother answering with excuses about being too busy, or any other number of extra-legal stalling tactics. If you are up against a corrupt police department then they may have other ways to force you to stop bothering them which we can't help with. Your best course, as @security_paranoid says, is probably to talk to a lawyer about your wider problem.

As a rule the police are not required to answer questions about specific investigations because that could help criminals to evade detection. You might get some information about their general use (e.g. which licenses they have purchased and how often it gets deployed).

LAW does not allow legal advice. I expect the migration to be rejected based on that.

@PaulJohnson I can tell you for certain that that is not really a rule, or at least that such a rule would be limited to specific jurisdictions. In Ohio, for instance, investigative materials are public records, with only narrow exceptions.
